# Could someone explain to me why my function returns 0 instead of 1?

Tags: c++

Isn't the counter supposed to reach the '\0' in line 1 and line 2 that way both can't be different from each other so the function skips the condition and returns 1?

```
int funcX(const char *, const char *);

int main()
{
    char string1[40] = "line1",
    string2[40] = "line2";
    cout << funcX(string1, string2) << endl << endl;
    cin >> string1;
    return 0;
}

int funcX(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    for (; *s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0'; s1++, s2++) {
        cout << *s1 << " " << *s2<<endl;
        if (*s1 != *s2) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Bah i'm such an idiot ,i though the if statement was out of the for loop ,thanks @qxz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns `0` because `*s1 != *s2` at the fifth character (`*s1=='1'`, `*s2=='2'`). The loop never reaches the sixth (null, `'\0'`) character.

[Looking at the output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51b812f740a3d40a), you can see that at that index the two `char`s are different.